# How to prevent django admin user from changing user email address with particular domain?

Tags: python, django-forms, django-admin

In my django admin, superuser is able to change the email address for any user.

I want superuser to prevent changing email for the user if that email address is from particular domain.

for ex: if user's email address is abc@restricteddomain.com then superuser should not be able to change this email to any other email address. I'm not able to fetch the old value using self.cleaned_data('email').

How to achieve this goal for admin site? I tried overrriding clean() method but it didn't work

Comment: Are you using django's default user model?

Comment: No I have custom user model